# Interaction hamiltonian of Unruh-De Witt detector in Schrödinger picture

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, hamiltonian-formalism

Unruh-De Witt detector is a qubit following a classical trajectory coupled as a monopole to a quantized scalar field; as such, the detector is a two-level system $|\text{g}\rangle,|\text{e}\rangle$ with energy separation $\Omega$ and the hamiltonian of the system in the Schrödinger representation resembles that of a, maybe more familiar, Jaynes-Cummings model
\begin{equation*}
 \hat{H} = \hat{H}_0 + \hat{H}_{\text{i}}%c \left( \hat{\sigma}_- +  \hat{\sigma}_+ \right) \hat{\phi}(r) 
 \quad \text{where} \quad \hat{H}_0 = \Omega |\text{e}\rangle\langle\text{e}| + \hat{H}_{\text{f}}
\end{equation*}
in which $\hat{H}_{\text{f}}$ is the hamiltonian of the free field and $\hat{H}_{\text{i}}$ at the moment is not explicited. The usual next step (e.g. sec. 3.3 in *Quantum Fields in Curved Space* by Birrel and Davies, 1982) is passing to the interaction picture, where the interaction hamiltonian has the form
\begin{equation*}
c \left( e^{-\mathrm{i} \Omega \tau} \hat{\sigma}_- + e^{\mathrm{i} \Omega \tau} \hat{\sigma}_+ \right) \hat{\phi}(t,r)
\end{equation*}
in which $c$ is a coupling constant and $\hat{\sigma}_-,\hat{\sigma}_+$ are the basic two-level ladder operators.

There are two very important things here

- $\hat{\phi}(t,r)$ is a *free* field operator with Minkowski coordinates
- $\tau$ is the detector's proper time

and since the interaction hamiltonian in the interaction picture is related to $\hat{H}_{\text{i}}$ in the Schrödinger picture via
\begin{equation*}
e^{\mathrm{i} \hat{H}_0 t} \hat{H}_{\text{i}} e^{-\mathrm{i} \hat{H}_0 t}
\end{equation*}
then we should have
\begin{gather*}
c \left( e^{-\mathrm{i} \Omega \tau} \hat{\sigma}_- + e^{\mathrm{i} \Omega \tau} \hat{\sigma}_+ \right) \hat{\phi}(t,r)
=
e^{\mathrm{i} \hat{H}_0 t} \hat{H}_{\text{i}} e^{-\mathrm{i} \hat{H}_0 t}
\\
\hat{H}_{\text{i}}
=
c e^{-\mathrm{i} \Omega |\text{e}\rangle\langle\text{e}| t} \left( e^{-\mathrm{i} \Omega \tau} \hat{\sigma}_- + e^{\mathrm{i} \Omega \tau} \hat{\sigma}_+ \right) e^{\mathrm{i} \Omega |\text{e}\rangle\langle\text{e}| t} e^{-\mathrm{i} \hat{H}_{\text{f}} t}\hat{\phi}(t,r) e^{\mathrm{i} \hat{H}_{\text{f}} t}
\end{gather*}
where
\begin{equation*}
e^{-\mathrm{i} \hat{H}_{\text{f}} t}\hat{\phi}(t,r) e^{\mathrm{i} \hat{H}_{\text{f}} t} = \hat{\phi}(0,r)
\end{equation*}
as expected in a Schrödinger picture. What I do not understand is the detector's term
\begin{equation*}
c e^{-\mathrm{i} \Omega |\text{e}\rangle\langle\text{e}| t} \left( e^{-\mathrm{i} \Omega \tau} \hat{\sigma}_- + e^{\mathrm{i} \Omega \tau} \hat{\sigma}_+ \right) e^{\mathrm{i} \Omega |\text{e}\rangle\langle\text{e}| t}
\end{equation*}
that, since $\hat{\sigma}_-=|\text{g}\rangle\langle\text{e}|$ and $\hat{\sigma}_+=|\text{e}\rangle\langle\text{g}|$, becomes
\begin{equation*}
c \left( e^{-\mathrm{i} \Omega ( \tau - t ) } |\text{g}\rangle\langle\text{e}| + e^{\mathrm{i} \Omega ( \tau - t ) } |\text{e}\rangle\langle\text{g}| \right)
\end{equation*}
that to me has a totally obscure meaning, especially if we were in the Schrödinger picture.
So, in conclusion, is it really
\begin{equation*}
\hat{H}_{\text{i}} = c \left( e^{-\mathrm{i} \Omega ( \tau - t ) } |\text{g}\rangle\langle\text{e}| + e^{\mathrm{i} \Omega ( \tau - t ) } |\text{e}\rangle\langle\text{g}| \right) \hat{\phi}(0,r) \quad \text{?}
\end{equation*}
and, alternatevely, what would be in this case the correct way of having in the same hamiltonian two operators in very different reference systems?

Comment: I actually found more clear a related article to that one suggested in the answer below, and is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.01867.pdf  I need to read it again, but I think goes straight to the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your free Hamiltonian $H_0$ you need a factor $\frac{d\tau}{dt}$ in front of the qubit term (but not the field term) which makes sure the $H_0(t)$ generates time translations in Minkowski time for the field, but proper time for the qubit.

If you include this factor in your free Hamiltonian, and then stick it into the free time evolution operator $U(t):=Te^{ -i \int_0^t H_0(t) dt'}$ you will get the right answer.

See this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.10010.pdf on time reparametrizations for this model and more detail on why these factors are needed. When this factor is properly included you will get $|\text{g}\rangle \langle \text{e} | + |\text{e}\rangle \langle \text{g} | $ in the S picture as your answer with no oscillatory factors

Comment: Thank you, I saw the factor you cite somewhere, but I didn't understand much, I go immediately to read the article

Comment: To convince yourself, do the exercise of plugging in $H_0(t) = \Omega |\text{e}\rangle \langle \text{e}| \frac{d\tau(t)}{dt} \otimes I_{\text{f}} + I_{\text{UDW}} \otimes H_{\text{f}}$ into the unitary time evolution operator I quote above. Notice I explicitly wrote the identities on each hilbert space which will help. Use that $\frac{d\tau(t')}{dt'} dt'= d\tau$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll finish the article and try